# Get All post that is in table

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I have table that save in it the user id and post id.

Now in some page i need to show all post for user_id (1) for example.

how can i display all post that user_id is 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress queries (using `WP_Query` or `get_posts()` either) support `post__in` argument to retrieve specific set of posts by IDs.

So you would need to produce such list from your custom storage and then use in a query.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `WP_Query`, there have a param for the author, like the follow example, that give you all posts to user with the ID `1`.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'author'         => 1,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'showposts'      => -1,
    'nopaging'       => true
) );
```

The result can you use in a loop, also a example.

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    ?><ul><?php
    while( $query->have_posts ) {
        the_post();
        ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a></li>
        <?php
    }
    ?></ul><?php
}
```